# Convert time and date to mysql datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a date in the following format in my DB `September 20, 2011 18:00:00`
But this will not work if I want to apply date functions in mysql like delete the record with this date or older. The correct format to do this needs to be `2011-09-20 18:00:00`.

So any easy way to convert the first date to the second date? Or is it just easier to make another field in the table for the datetime format?

Comment: You should save dates in `datetime` format, not as `varchar`. Save data, not presentation.

Comment: of course, stupid of me.. rookie misstake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = 'September 20, 2011 18:00:00';
$unix_timestamp = strtotime($s);
$mysql_timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$unix_timestamp); // now looks like '2011-09-20 18:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in mysql directly, but you can create a helper script.

pseudo code following:

```
$data = db_query("SELECT id, date FROM footable");

foreach ($data => $item) {
  // repeat line below for all months
  $new_item string_replace($item, "September", 9)
  $new_date = regex_replace($new_item, 
    "([0-9]{1,2}) ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{4}) (.*)", 
    "$3-$2-$1 $4");
  db_query("UPDATE footable SET date = $newdate");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see an all-MySQL answer. :)

Assuming your "datetime" field is called "dt", you can change it to the proper type (`DATETIME`) by first reformatting the strings into something MySQL will recognize as the string format of a `DATETIME`, and then changing the column's type.  Have a backup handy in case you or I have a typo below.

```
SET sql_mode=ansi;    -- for || operator

UPDATE tbl SET dt = LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, ' ', -2), 4)            -- YYYY
                    || '-'
                    || LPAD(FIELD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, ' ', 1),       -- MM
                                  'January', 'February', 'March',
                                  'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
                                  'August', 'September', 'October',
                                  'November', 'December'),
                            2, '0')
                    || '-'
                    || LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(                         -- DD
                                        SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, ',', 1),
                            ' ', -1), 2, '0')
                    || ' '
                    || SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, ' ', -1);                 -- hh:mm:ss

ALTER TABLE tbl CHANGE dt dt DATETIME;
```